# Longest palindrome size with suffix trees

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, suffix-trees

Suppose that I want to get the size of the biggest palindrome in a string s, and I am restricted to do it using suffix trees what is the best complexity I will get and why? I checked other answers but I find them highly confused.
EDIT:
I tried create a suffix tree with the string and the inverse of the string and use a BFS to find the biggest levels that are common to the two strings and if the suffix starts at the same point the suffix string will have the same size to the longest string of.

I think this solution is based on others found in the Internet I said that is $O(n)$ as creating suffix trees and doing a BFS in a tree are bouth $O(n)$, but I don't believe in the correctness of this.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you already have an answer, please include it in your post. It's unfair to hide information from would-be answerers.

Comment: Also, we discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Is there a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.